# Change switch button text color

Tags: android

I have successfully able to create a switch button in my application using the following custom class available in Github [Switch Button Demo class](https://github.com/pellucide/Android-Switch-Demo-pre-4.0/blob/master/android-switch-demo/src/com/appscumen/example/MySwitch.java)

Here is the snapshot what i am getting [image: Swith button]

All is working good except one thing , I want to make text color to Black for unchecked state. I mean **"OFF"** text color is black when it is not selected. I tried to put some condition on my custom class but it not giving me the proper result.
My style.xml file is like this

```
     <style name="mySwitchStyle">
          <item name="track">@drawable/switch_track_green</item>
          <item name="thumb">@drawable/background_fenced</item>
          <item name="switchTextAppearanceAttrib">@style/mySwitchTextAppearance</item>
          <item name="textOn">ON</item>
          <item name="textOff">OFF</item>
          <item name="pushStyle">false</item>
          <item name="textOnThumb">true</item>
          <item name="thumbExtraMovement">0dp</item>
          <item name="thumbTextPadding">6dp</item>
          <item name="trackTextPadding">6dp</item>
         <item name="switchMinWidth">69dp</item>
         <item name="switchMinHeight">36dp</item>
         <item name="switchPadding">6dp</item>
      </style>

      <style name="mySwitchTextAppearance">
          <item name="textColor">#FFeeFFee</item>
          <item name="textColorHighlight">#FFeeFFee</item>
          <item name="textColorHint">#FFeeFFee</item>
         <item name="textColorLink">#FFeeFFee</item>
         <item name="textSize">16sp</item>
         <item name="textStyle">normal</item>
      </style>
```

I tried to change the textColorHighlight, textColorHint, textColorLink to Black color but not giving me the desired result. Please help me to   acheive the desired result.

Comment: were you able to achieve this?

Comment: It was not working at all in my case at that point of time so I had tried the different solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `textColor` as [color-list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:color="#ffffff"/> <!-- checked, white -->
    <item android:color="#000000"/> <!-- default, black -->
</selector>
```

**Update:**

Use [SwitchCompact](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html)

> SwitchCompat is a version of the Switch widget which on devices back to API v7. It does not make any attempt to use the platform provided widget on those devices which it is available normally.

Comment: I tried this one but it's not changing the text color

Comment: @user3649775, it would work, maybe something wrong during its implementation, you can try to use `SwitchCompact` from Google's support library. It will allow to use switch at early versions of Android.